# How can I save a NSTextField in CoreData?

Tags: macos, core-data, nsdocument

I have found this video that explain how to save using core data, when you are using a NSTable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Du_6By97sM&list=PLE83F832121568D36&index=31

But I'm trying to have just a collection of Form elements, like NSTextField that get saved to a document.

I figured they would use a single row within the Entity, but I can't figure if it is even possible.

Comment: You wouldn't be saving the `NSTextField`, you would be saving the text string that it contains. Is that your only data? Why in Core Data?

Comment: Yes I would want to be saving the value.  I plan on adding lots of elements, but I wanted to simplify the example.

Comment: I was wanting to use Core Data because of all the bits you go for free.  Migrations, and Undos.  I figured it would end up being the equivalent of one row holding all the values, but don't know really where to being or what to google for

Comment: Start with a general Core Data tutorial. Consider groups of data that are related to each other. Try not to store lots of unrelated data in a single object, and don't think of Core Data as tables and rows...

Comment: I'm struggling to find relavent tutorials for core data that relate to OSX, rather than iOS.

Comment: The Core Data part should be the same on both platforms, it's only the UI displaying the data that changes.